# Caffe error make test

Tags: caffe

I have already installed cudnn and cuda in the ubuntu, and I

> make all -j4

under the caffe-master directory, it passed well. but when I

> make test

it shows:

```
CXX src/caffe/test/test_im2col_layer.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:40:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19,
                 from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,
                 from src/caffe/test/test_im2col_layer.cpp:5:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp: In function ‘void caffe::cudnn::createPoolingDesc(cudnnPoolingStruct**, caffe::PoolingParameter_PoolMethod, cudnnPoolingMode_t*, int, int, int, int, int, int)’:
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:127:41: error: too few arguments to function ‘cudnnStatus_t cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor(cudnnPoolingDescriptor_t, cudnnPoolingMode_t, cudnnNanPropagation_t, int, int, int, int, int, int)’
         pad_h, pad_w, stride_h, stride_w));
                                         ^
./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:15:28: note: in definition of macro ‘CUDNN_CHECK’
     cudnnStatus_t status = condition; \
                            ^
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/cudnn.hpp:5:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:40,
                 from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19,
                 from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,
                 from src/caffe/test/test_im2col_layer.cpp:5:
/usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h:799:27: note: declared here
 cudnnStatus_t CUDNNWINAPI cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor(
                           ^
Makefile:572: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_im2col_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_im2col_layer.o] Error 1
```

I installed the newest version of cudnn(cudnn v5 library for linux) and cuda(cuda 7.5). Anyone could tell me how to solve the problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

CuDNN v5 is incompatible with caffe. You can try making a fork and merging this: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3919/files , but it is not officially supported.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the latest Caffe (November 8 2016) states that it supports CUDA 7+.

I still needed to fix this issue though as I was using an older branch of caffe linked to a faster-rcnn github repo. I was upgrading it to support CUDNN 5 and CUDA 8. Please note that I am not a Caffe expert, however all the tests ran successfully after I'd gotten it to compile successfully.

For the methods whose signatures appear to have changed, I found there are also _v3 and _v4 equivalents (for me I took a look in /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h). I changed the method that was failing

FROM:
    CUDNN_CHECK(cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor(*pool_desc, *mode, h, w,

TO:
    CUDNN_CHECK(cudnnSetPooling2dDescriptor**_v3**(*pool_desc, *mode, h, w,
 4. src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu

I needed to do similar things in the following files:

1. src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu
2. src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cu
3. src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu
4. src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cu

Hope that helps for you too!

Comment: Could you show how your line 33 of cudnn_conv_layer.cu looks like? Without changing anything I get error regarding incompatible parameters on this line, and when I add "_v1", "_v2", "_v3", "_v4" or "_v5" to cudnnAddTensor I get: `src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu(33): error: identifier "cudnnAddTensor_v5" is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

try `make clean` --> `make all` --> `make test` --> `make runtest`. if you have a permission error use `sudo`.